# Unable to pass a command to ssh while using pkexec, gives me an error

Tags: ssh, pkexec

I am writing a script that relies on `pkexec` as the machine is hardened and `sudo` will not work. I allow `pkexec` to temporarily not prompt the user for a password, so any command will work directly.

If I manually log in to SSH and have a session open and run a command like: `pkexec service iptables restart` it works, however, if I try doing something like `ssh username@127.0.0.1 "pkexec service iptables restart"` I get the following error:

```
Cannot run program service: no such file or directory
```

So it has something to do with me passing `pkexec` as a parameters.

Comment: Did you specify a path?  `...."pkexec /sbin/service iptables restart"`

Comment: OK, converted into a full answer with explanation as to why this works.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a `ssh remotehost some_command` type command your `$PATH` may not be set to the values that you expect.

For example, we can see the PATH in my current login shell doesn't match the remote PATH, even though I'm logging into the same machine:

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/sweh/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/u/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/etc:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/usr/sbin

$ ssh localhost 'echo $PATH'
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
```

For this reason it's normal to specify the full path name to commands.

In this instance the error message `Cannot run program service: no such file or directory` means that the `pkexec` command was found (it's probably on the default PATH) but the `service` command wasn't.

So specify `/sbin/service`... eg

```
ssh username@127.0.0.1 "pkexec /sbin/service iptables restart"
```